# DTO vs hashmap: maintainability vs memory efficiency

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm having a debate on out DTOs. Whenever I need to return a subset or superset of the domain object's fields I create a new class with these fields use it in the code. Even if there is only single usecase for that.

#### Point 1 - eat more memory, write less code

This highly increases maintainability and readability, since my service method has only two lines of code. But if I used a hashmap, then there would be magic strings and no compile-time checking.

#### Point 2 - eat less memory, write more code

After returning the DTOto the client it's class metadata is still in the class loader. But if I used a hashmap, then I would not have this overhead. More impact if there are a lot of DTO classes.

What pragmatically has more impact?

Comment: You're not seriously considering performance aspects in a scenario like this, are you?

Comment: @Kayaman personally, I think that I should keep the dto class but the colleague insists that's `super bad`

Comment: Super bad because of performance or other reasons?

Comment: @Kayaman my opinion is `point 1` their is `point 2`

Comment: Traditionally the people most worried about performance are the ones who have the least understanding about it. That seems to be the case here too. The additional class is irrelevant, except if you have lots of DTOs it can become annoying for the developer to write and maintain them. From a performance point of view it has no effect.

Comment: @Kayaman I think the key is in `memory` rather than `performance` (perhaps, I misused the word here -- edited question). I tend to create a DTO class even if it is only used in a single usecase. Their point is that if I keep doing that for every such situation I will end up with a lot of DTO classes filling up the class loader with their metadata. I understand that our application will each a bit more memory but I think that is worth it, unlike my coleague

Comment: There are thousands of classes loaded in the classloader even before you start adding your DTOs. Your handwritten classes are **insignificant**.

Comment: Also accessing values from DTO will be always faster than accessing Map, it is also possible that it will actually use *less* memory as Map nodes/buckets add overhead

Comment: Thanks, Kayaman, user158037, that is convincing enough to win the argument! Please, post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily fill up the metaspace with classes, especially handwritten ones (as opposed to generated etc.). Of course you can constrain yourself so you have only minimal space available, but in a normal scenario it's not very likely.

So the effect of a class on the performance or memory use is completely irrelevant. The only reason you might want to avoid writing DTOs is because it requires programmer effort to write and maintain them. This can become problematic, but there are ways to deal with those too (such as the aforementioned generated classes).

So there's no (performance or memory) reason **not** to use DTOs, and there are plenty of reasons not to use `Maps` as you said. Type safety and code readability being the most obvious ones.

Comment: Thanks! We actually use project `Lombok`, so besides fields, in the worst case, I have to write custom constructor but that's it.

Comment: Ah yeah, that takes a lot of boilerplate out.